# if statement after math operation Syntax error in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Hi i'm new to OCaml and working on a problem. The method below isn't what I have to do but I have narrowed the error in my code down to this. I was wondering why it works if I take away the x = x *. 2.0 but when I add it I get a syntax error on the if statement

```ml
let idk (x: float) =
x = x *. 2.0
if (x > 0.0) then true else false ;;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are thinking of `x = x *. 2.0` as a statement that changes the value of `x`. But in OCaml, the value of a variable can't be changed.

In OCaml expressions `=` is the equality comparsion operator. So `x = x *. 2.0` is a boolean expression. I.e., it's something that's either true or false.

Since you don't really want to have two expressions after each other, the details of the syntax error probably aren't useful.

Although you can't change the value of a variable, you can have any number of local variables you like. The way to declare a local variable looks like this:

```
let my_local_variable = expression1 in expression2
```

To get the effect you are looking far (I think), you could write something like this:

```
let idk (x: float) =
   let local_x = x *. 2.0 in
   if (local_x > 0.0) then true else false
```

Comment: Additionally `(local_x > 0.0)` is also a boolean expression that you can return directly. No need for `if` there and the type of x doesn't have to be specified: `let idk x = let local_x = x *. 2.0 in (local_x > 0.0)`.

Comment: Sure, and `2.0 *. x > 0.0` is virtually the same as `x > 0.0`. So the entire function can be written `let idk x = x > 0.0`. Or even shorter, `let idk = ((<) 0.0)`. But I figure first things first.